# iOS 7 I want iOS 8 latest version

Tags: iphone

When I click on software update the little working icon shows up and all it does is spin and spin like it's working but the software latest version never pops up so that I can download and install. What do I do ?

Comment: Do you have a computer you can use?

Comment: @Buscar웃 What difference would being logged in make for an iOS update?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Let Kim download the iOS update through iTunes.

Comment: The spin loop issue is in jailbroken devices or due to slow internet connection. Did you jailbreak your device? If you did, download .ipsw file from Internet and restore by holding Option (Mac)/Shift (Windows) and selecting "Restore" button.

Comment: What iPhone are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Shut the iPhone completely off and turn it back on.

Make sure the iPhone is at 100% charge and still plugged into the charger.

Attempt to do an "over the air" update wirelessly via Software Update under Settings.

If that fails then update the iPhone via iTunes.

Have a look at [Update the iOS software on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204) for steps using either method.

Make sure you have adequate free space to preform the upgrade.  Have a look at [If you need more space for an iOS update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203097) if need be.